# New-Mailbox creation error

Tags: powershell, office365, powershell-cmdlet

We try to create new-mailbox in office 365 account using the cmdlet

**New-Mailbox -UserPrincipalName chris@contoso.com -Alias chris -Database "Mailbox Database 1"**

in WindowsPowershell ISE.To our surprise -UserPrincipalName is not a recognizable.However,using the following cmdlet ,we are able to create new mail box

**New-Mailbox -Name "abcd" -MicrosoftOnlineServicesID "abcd@abcdwe.onmicrosoft.com" -Password $Password**

here -MicrosoftOnlineServicesID is well recognizable and runs successfully also.

Note:I mean recognizable since when I type -MicrosoftOnlineServicesID in Windows Powershell ISE,the intellisense pops up a suggestion.

My question is why is the parameter **-MicrosoftOnlineServicesID**  is recognizable and why the prameter **-UserPrincipalName** is not recognizable?

Note:In the same way as -UserPrincipalName , the parameter -TemplateInstance and many other parameters are not recognizable or not working properly.

Please carify what we need to include/import to make these cmdlets recognizable.

Comment: Hm, according to [Microsoft's website](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997663(v=exchg.150).aspx) you should be able to use that.